# Glass mapper page editor mode

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper

I have an issue with glass mapper in page editor mode. when i am trying to open the page in the page editor mode i got below error. The same code is working properly in local machines. When the code deployed to dev and qa we are getting the below Please help us

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectToSwitchTo
>
> at Sitecore.Common.Switcher 2.Enter(TValue objectToSwitchTo)
>      at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression 1 field,
>   Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, C

Comment: Can you post the code where this editable field appears? Also more information about your Model would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Thanks FOr the reply. I got issue resolved... The problem is glassmapper.mvc.config was not deployed properly in my dev server..